# Simplest way to use a DatagridView with Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, datagridview

I have never used datagrids and such, but today I came across a simple problem and decided to "databind" stuff to finish this faster, however I've found that it doesn't work as I was expecting.

I though that by doing something as simple as:

```
 var q = from cust in dc.Customers
         where cust.FirstName == someString
         select cust;

 var list = new BindingList<Customer>(q.ToList());
 return list;
```

Then using that list in a DataGridView1.DataSource was all that I needed, however, no matter how much I google, I can't find a decent example on how to populate (for add/edit/modify) the results of a single table query into a DataGridView1. Most samples talk about ASP.NET which I lack, this is WinForms.

Any ideas?

I've came across other posts and the GetNewBindingList, but that doesn't seem to change much.

What am I missing (must be obvious)?

Answer (score 5):

You can just bind the IQueryable result to the DataGridView, not sure why you converting it to a BindingList, is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: To provide two way binding so that changes in the DataGridView can be notified?

Comment: Well, no reason. As I've mentioned I'm 100% new to DataGrids, that's an example I found somewhere in google land. :S (But it doesn't work)

Answer (score 3):

You might have a look at the `TableList<T>` from [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/browse_thread/thread/49fd93763695c4ad/) - based on `BindingList<T>`, but with hooks into the data-context.

Comment: Oh, I've seen that post before (had it open in one of the Tabs), I just realized it was your post! :)

Will re-read it and ask if I have questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, see the answer of thedugas: [unable-to-edit-datagridview-populated-with-results-of-linq-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311683/unable-to-edit-datagridview-populated-with-results-of-linq-query)

Next to a BindingList, it uses a BindingSource. And instead of the `MergeEntry` class you use your `Customer` class.

Answer (score 0):

Just bind it.

```
    var q = from cust in dc.Customers
            where cust.FirstName == someString
            select cust;
    DataGridView1.DataSource = q
```

No need to convert it to list.

Comment: This won't allow for editing in the DataGridView. He mentioned "add/edit/modify".

Answer (score 0):

> string = "12/11/2014"

Try this:

```
try
{
    con_a_refacionesDataContextDataContext con = new con_a_refacionesDataContextDataContext();
    BindingSource b = new BindingSource();
    b.DataSource = from eq in con.Venta 
                   where eq.fecha_dia == st 
                   select eq;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = b;
}
catch
{
}
```